# Simple jQuery .each problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL with 9 anchor tags, each with the class 'highlight'.

Here is a bit of Javascript with jQuery:

```
        var titles = $('a.highlight');
        jQuery.each(titles, alert(titles.length));
```

What I expect this bit of code to do:
Alert 9 times, the number 9.

What this bit of code actually does:
Alerts 1 time the number 9.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) calls a function you pass it for each item it finds in the given collection. You are passing an expression that is evaluated immediately.  You need to wrap the expression in an anonymous function:

```
jQuery.each(titles, function() {
    alert(titles.length)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
jQuery.each( titles, function( index, title ) {
  console.log( 'the title at index ', index, ' is ', title );
} );
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) for the `each` function.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a novice myself, but shouldn't it be titles.each(), not jQuery.each()?

Comment: You can use either way, jQuery.each is just a generic iterator.
http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each

Either way I get the same result though.

Comment: My bad.  I thought you were trying to call $(...).each().